# Can you use the starting money from your background to buy items before the campaign starts?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, equipment

I'm playing my first campaign soon. While making my character, I noticed that you get money from your background. I was wondering if you can use this money to buy basic shop items before the campaign starts.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour].  This question is similar to [some](/questions/24637) [other](/questions/122552) [questions](/questions/46692) here.  Do those related questions address your concerns?